# remove in Red Black Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, red-black-tree

Why does the method remove(x) in the RedBlackTree implementation

perform the assignment u:parent = w:parent? Shouldn’t this already be done by the call to

splice(w)?

Comment: Do you have any code we can look at?

Comment: You'll need to at least identify which "the RedBlackTree implementation" you're talking about. There are quite a few of them out there...